# how can hide a column while printing from DataTable using TableTools

Tags: datatable, tabletools

Code to print excel and pdf

I would like to hide a column from a `datatable` using `tabletool`.

```
var tableTools = new $.fn.DataTable.TableTools(table, {
    'aButtons': [
        {
            'sExtends': 'xls',
            'sButtonText': 'Excel',
            'sFileName': 'Article.xls'
        },
        {
            'sExtends': 'print',
        },
        {
            'sExtends': 'pdf',
            'sFileName': 'Article.pdf',
            'bFooter': false
        },
    ],
    'sSwfPath': '//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
```

Comment: Check https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "columns" to show (skipping as not to show)  as example below:

```
{extend: 'print',
titleAttr: 'Print the results',
title: '',
exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible',
    stripHtml: false,
    **columns: [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]**,
},
text: '<i class="fa fa-print fa-lg text-success"></i>',
message: 'REPORT NAME' ,
customize: function (win) {
    $(win.document.body)
        .css('font-size', '10pt')
        .prepend(
            '<img src="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
        );

    $(win.document.body).find('table')
        .addClass('compact')
        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
}
```

}